# Get all methods

Tags: php, authentication

I'm attempting to build a role based access control in our PHP framework. The framework is on MVC architecture so every path works on `/controller/action/param`. We can get the controller and action on initialization and store them in variables, $controller, $action. Now my idea is to use a class to check the permissions of this action like:

```
Auth::permissions($controller, $action);
```

Now I'm hoping I could somehow create a script which would find all public methods of controllers inside a /modules/ folder. This way I could just run a script and it would update all controller actions as a list to the database, where we would get the role permissions from. This way I could avoid inserting all controller actions manually. Getting all the controllers is very easy as the folder structure is as:

```
/modules
    /controller
        controller.php
```

So I can just find all subdirectories on modules and add .php in the end. **My question is that can I get the file's public methods somehow?**

```
class Example extends Controller {
    public function main() {
        return 'foo';
    }
}
```

This way I could store this in the database as

```
example | main | role_id
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php Not quite all the functions from the file, but you will get all the functions from the class. with attributes etc.

Comment: File does not have methods. Nor does it have actions or controllers.

Comment: @TanuelMategi http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php no need for reflection class for getting the public methods names.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. The RBAC part should be handled by a router. Before your controller gets instantiated, you should check whether a logged in user has enough rights

Comment: I am still building this so I don't have all the datails yet. Your debate about my way of doing it does not answer my question.

Comment: Using the ReflectionClass actually worked. I forgot I had all the files in a certain namespace. Thanks! If you want credit just add it as an answer. I'll accep tit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a little code that can help you:

```
<?php
class Example {
    public function main() {
        return 'foo';
    }
    private function privatefunc(){
    }
    public function anotherpublicfunc(){
    }
}


$reflector = new ReflectionClass("Example");

foreach($reflector->getMethods() as $method){
    if($method->isPublic()) {
        echo "Method ".$method->name." is public".PHP_EOL;
    }else{
        echo "Method ".$method->name." is not public".PHP_EOL;
    }
}
?>
```

output:

```
Method main is public
Method privatefunc is not public
Method anotherpublicfunc is public
```

Comment: Yes I will. Just have to wait because it was so quick. You actually forgot to make the $method a ReflectionMethod object. You can't get isPublic without it. A simpler way is to make $reflector->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC)

Comment: the $method is a ReflectionMethod actually ;) you can find out by using `var_dump($method)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get public methods of a class then you can use `get_class_methods` read the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php)

```
class Car {

    public function permission_method_two() {

    }

    public function permission_method_three() {

    }

    private function private_function() {

    }

}

echo '<pre>'.print_r(get_class_methods('Car'),1).'</pre>';
// prints only public methods:

Array
(
    [0] => permission_method_two
    [1] => permission_method_three
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow convention:
- each public methods start without lowdash
- each private and protected method start with lowdash

Example

```
class Example
{
   public function publicMethod()
   {
   }

   private function _privateMethod()
   {
   }

   protected function _protectedMethod()
   {
   }

}
```

and then use http://php.net/manual/ru/function.get-class-methods.php

```
foreach(get_class_methods('Example') as $methodName){
   if(strpos($methodName, '_') !== 0) $publicMethod[] = $methodName; 
}
```